# Is it possible to build apps for iOS 8.1 in Xcode 5.1.1?

Tags: ios, xcode

Yesterday, I upgraded to iOS 8.1 and now I cannot build apps in Xcode 5.1.1. Is there or is there going to be an iOS 8.1 SDK that I can install on Xcode 5.1.1?

Comment: Nope. Install Xcode 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not going to be an iOS 8.1 SDK that you can install on Xcode 5.1.1. Apple doesn't support older versions of Xcode.

You can build apps that are compatible with iOS 8.1 with Xcode 5.x, but you can't use the new features of iOS 8.1.

Comment: And yet, there is a possibility! When you build your app in Xcode 6.1 and then return back to Xcode 5.1.1, you can actually build in Xcode 5.1.1 for iOS 8.1. However, this approach lacks the initial goal to be able to build apps without Xcode 6.1 right away.

Comment: @martinkabat Are you planning on using the iOS 8.1 APIs? I don't believe you'll get access to them if you're using Xcode 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to know that you can ONLY update to xcode 6.x if you have maverik or yosemite installed. Also Xcode 5.1 will NOT allow iPads with iOS 8.x installed to be used as a developing devices so you are stuck with using only the simulators. While facing the same issue i was trying to update to xcode 6.1 just to find out that it won't install on my Mountain Lion system. This means it's probably time to upgrade my OSX first.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dual boot machine that boots to 10.8.5 and 10.10.5.

On the 10.10.5 installation, I have Xcode 6.x and Xcode 7.2 (latest as of this writing).

I just built an iOS 8.x application using "Mountain Lion/Xcode 5.1.1/iOS SDK 8.1" and am debugging on an iPod Touch running 8.4.1.  In my 10.10 boot, I run Xcode7 and debug devices on iOS 9.2.

With some limitations, it is possible to use newer iOS SDKs with older Xcodes.  It depends on how many new language features are used in the SDK headers.  Apple SDK headers tend to be very well designed.  Simply copy the iOS 8 and device support files from the newer Xcode(s) to the older Xcode.  Obviously, you will not be able to design use 8.1 features in your Storyboards and XIBs.

For example:
Copy the iOS 8.x SDK from Xcode 6.x into Xcode 5.1.1

SOURCE FOLDER
/Volumes/MACOSX10.10/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

DESTINATION FOLDER
/Volumes/MACOSX10.8/Applications/Xcode5.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

And copy the appropriate Device Support files from the newer Xcode into the older Xcode:

SOURCE FOLDER
/Volumes/MACOSX10.10/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

DESTINATION FOLDER
/Volumes/MACOSX10.8/Applications/Xcode5.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
This method of munging Xcode has worked in a variety of forms since iOS 4.

In general, it is almost always possible to use the +1 newer SDK with the previous version of Xcode.  This is because (in theory) there is a switchover period when Apple is using the older toolchain to compile the newer tools.

ALSO, after installing the new SDKs, it may be necessary to recreate your project schemes before the hardware appears in the drop down on the Xcode toolbar.  Usually what I do is go into "Manage Schemes", select all the existing schemes and delete them.  Then, click "Autocreate Schemes Now".  This is a general technique for moving projects from one Xcode installation to another and seems to be important for hardware recognition.